# Porting existing android for Arm to Intel X86

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk

I am a bit of a newbie working with Android but I have come across an issue that I can't seem to find an answer for...

So I have an application for android that I can compile using gcc and targeting an ARM architecture-- all is good, works perfect.

We have found the app runs slow in comparison to a windows build, so I am trying to target for X86 instead.  Everything seemed to be working fine but I then hit an error once I tried to include a certain library-- the elastique audio time stretching lib.  I get this error:

```
[x86] StaticLibrary  : libcpufeatures.a
[x86] SharedLibrary  : libjuce_jni.so
/Applications/BeaconMountain/NDK/toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.8/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: error: jni/../../../elastique/lib/android/libelastiqueEfficient.a(elastiqueAPI.cpp.o): incompatible target
jni/../../../AudioStreamData.cpp:778: error: undefined reference to 'CElastiqueIf::DestroyInstance(CElastiqueIf*)'
```

My boss suggested that it might be that the libraries are only built for ARM.. is there a workaround here?  Or is the answer simply if the libs weren't built for the same target, then we are sol...?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

the library you're trying to include is indeed built for ARM, hence the `incompatible target` message.

I don't know this SDK and how you're including it on Android. But if you have something like:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := elastique/lib/android/libelastiqueEfficient.a
```

inside your Android.mk file, that means the same prebuilts are always included when you target any platform supported the NDK (armv5, armv7, x86, mips, and now all the 64bit archs as well)

The prebuilt libs that are included should always depend on the target architecture. A proper way to do this is to make one subfolder per target architecture (here by creating armeabi-v7a, armeabi, x86...) folders under `elastique/lib/android/`, and having the right `libelastiqueEfficient.a` in each of these. In that case you would change the current reference in Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := elastique/lib/android/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libelastiqueEfficient.a
```

But as you rightly guessed: you need this library to be built for each target and there are no workarounds. You can still contact the editor to ask him to fix its Android support.